# Can a multi-bulk reply include a status or error reply?

Tags: redis, protocols, network-protocols

I am implementing a parser for [the Redis network protocol](http://redis.io/topics/protocol).

While browsing the documentation, I came across the following statement:

> A Multi bulk reply is used to return an array of other replies. Every element of a Multi Bulk Reply can be of any kind, including a nested Multi Bulk Reply.

However, it was unclear to me whether or not this includes status or error replies since returning a status or an error reply within a multi-bulk reply really doesn't make any sense.

Are there any commands that would return a multi-bulk reply that includes a status or error reply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: transactions and Lua scripts.

See [Errors inside a transaction](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) for instance.

(Note: I had written another response that was completely wrong because I had misunderstood your question.)